# Creating particle/geo node setup where new particles start video sequence at birth?

Tags: particles

I know its an old question, but I'm hoping that some clever person has figured something out?!
The sprite sheet/offset approach, brilliantly explained by Santiago Pereira in the link below works well for short sequences, but for hundreds of frames it gets silly fast.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XP5DUOvu0JM&t=19s

Anyone? Blender devs?
Thanks in advance.